# Refactoring probot event functions into seperate file causes error: TypeError: handler is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, webhooks, probot

I have the vanilla probot event function from the [docs](https://probot.github.io/docs/hello-world/) that comments on new issues:

```js
const probotApp = app => {
  app.on("issues.opened", async context => {
    const params = context.issue({ body: "Hello World!" });
    return context.github.issues.createComment(params);
  });
}
```

This works fine.

I refactor the code into a separate file:

index.js

```js
const { createComment } = require("./src/event/probot.event");

const probotApp = app => {
  app.on("issues.opened", createComment);
}
```

probot.event.js

```
module.exports.createComment = async context => {
  const params = context.issue({ body: "Hello World!" });
  return context.github.issues.createComment(params);
};
```

But I receive this error:

```
ERROR (event): handler is not a function
    TypeError: handler is not a function
        at C:\Users\User\probot\node_modules\@octokit\webhooks\dist-node\index.js:103:14
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
        at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

When I create a test [as recommended in the docs](https://probot.github.io/docs/testing/) with a fixture and mock the event webhook call with nock this works fine. But when I create a real issue on GitHub this error is thrown.

How can I refactor the code into a separate file without causing the error?

Comment: in probot.event.js, instead of defining module.exports.createComment, try:
const createComment = async ...
then:
module.exports = {
    createEvent
}

Comment: Thanks, I found the error. It was indeed a wrong export :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was my mistake.

This is the whole `probot.event.js` file:

```
module.exports.createComment = async context => {
  const params = context.issue({ body: "Hello World!" });
  return context.github.issues.createComment(params);
};


module.exports = app => {
  // some other event definitions
}
```

By defining `module.exports = app` I overwrote the previous module.export. The `createComment` function was therefore never exported.

Removing `module.exports = app = { ... }` fixed it!